# Find $E[|\frac{X}{Y}|]$ for $X,Y iid \sim Exp(\lambda)$

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, exponential-distribution, ratio

Find $E\left[|\dfrac{X}{Y}|\right]$, $E\left[\dfrac{|X|}{Y}\right]$ and $E\left[\dfrac{X}{|Y|}\right]$ for $X,Y iid \sim Exp(\lambda)$

Does this differ from solving $E\left[\dfrac{X}{Y}\right]$?

I would solve $E\left[\dfrac{X}{Y}\right]$? by finding the density of Z and then finding the expectation of the random variable Z with this distribution.

> 2. Distribution of $Z = Y/X$.
>
> If $X,Y$ are independent exponentials with rates $\lambda,\mu$, then
> $Y = ZX$ and one way to do it is \begin{align*} f_Z(z) &=\int_0^\infty
>  f_X(x)f_Y(zx)\left|\frac{dy}{dz}\right|dx\\ &= \int_0^\infty \lambda
>  e^{-\lambda x}\cdot \mu e^{-\mu zx}|x|\,dx\\ &= \int_0^\infty
>  \lambda\mu e^{-(\lambda +\mu z)x}|x|\,dx\\ &=
>  \frac{\lambda\mu}{(\lambda+\mu z)^2}. \end{align*}

Comment: Note that $\mathbb P(X\geqslant 0) = \mathbb P(Y\geqslant 0)=1$ so the absolute values can be ignored.

Comment: By that logic, $E(X+Y)=E(|X+Y|)$?

Comment: Do you know how to work out $E[1/Y]$?

Comment: Yes, Are you suggesting that X and $1/Y$ are independent random variables?

Comment: It's a special case of an [old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33778/cdf-of-a-ratio-of-exponential-variables). Also see [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76175).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will instead consider the case where $X\sim\mathrm{Expo}(\lambda)$ and $Y\sim\mathrm{Expo}(\mu)$ since it generalizes the result and the computations are much the same.

For $t>0$ we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P\left(\frac XY>t\right) &= \iint_{\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2\ :\ 0\leqslant ty\leqslant x\}} \lambda\mu e^{-\lambda x}e^{-\mu y}\ \mathsf d(x\times y)\\
&= \int_0^\infty \left(\int_{ty}^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\ \mathsf dx \right) \mu e^{-\mu y}\ \mathsf dy\\
&= \int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda  ty}\mu e^{-\mu y}\ \mathsf dy\\
&= \frac{\mu }{\mu +\lambda  t}.
\end{align}
Since $\mathbb P(X>0) = \mathbb P(Y>0)=1$, we may compute the expectation of $\frac XY$ by integrating the survivor function above over $(0,\infty)$:
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{\mu }{\mu +\lambda  t}\ \mathsf dt = +\infty.
\end{align}
We conclude that this random variable does not have finite expectation.

Comment: I think you forgot a mu in your integral at the first step but corrected it on subsequent steps.

Comment: Are you saying that because $E[\frac{X}{Y}] \geq \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\mu}{\mu+\lambda t} dt=\infty$, then $E[\frac{X}{Y}] \geq \infty$ and therefore doesn't exist?

Comment: I see no missing $\mu$. In general, if $Y$ is a continuous random variable with density $f_Y$ satisfying $f_Y(0)>0$ then $\frac 1Y$ is not integrable, and so if $X,Y$ are i.i.d. then $\frac XY$ is not integrable.

Comment: How do you know that the range of t is from zero to infinity rather than from x/y to infinity ? Or 0 to x/y?

Comment: @Numbers $X$ and $Y$ take values in $(0,\infty)$, and so too does $\frac XY$. For a positive number divided by a positive number is a positive number...